# Develop function get_template_part in functions.php

Tags: functions

Is it possible to develop a function shortcode with get_template_part() in functions.php ? Something like this

```
function custom_code( $atts ){
    echo get_template_part( 'page', 'example' );
}
add_shortcode( 'custom', 'custom_code' );
```

thanks

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 4):

`get_template_part` is echoing the HTML code. and the shortcode function must return the content.

then you can try that :

```
function custom_code($attr, $content, $tag)
{

    ob_start();

    get_template_part( 'page', 'example' );

    $content = ob_get_clean();


    return $content;

}

add_shortcode( 'custom', 'custom_code' );
```

Comment: I don't understand! Excuse i'm a newbie.
I want use the shortcode....in your code where is the shortcode?

Comment: he's assuming you left your shortcode line:  add_shortcode( 'custom', 'custom_code' );  Now, if in a page, you use [custom]. it will call this function.

Comment: **rudtek** is right, I improved my answer a little bit.